# Using phantomjs to capture partial page contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, phantomjs

Does anyone know how to get phantomjs to screen capture partial page contents of a 3rd party web page?

For example, suppose a bookmarklet might figure out the element to capture, to send back to the server for snapping.

Is there a way to get phantomjs to render the contents of just that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need something to render a screenshot on the client, rather than on the server.

html2cancas let's you do what you want, but with some limitations.

You can get the script here:http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Include html2canvas and do:

```
var element =     
document.getElementById("myEl");
html2canvas(myEl, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  }
});
```

Comment: That's an awesome library - thanks for the reference. In my case, I should explain that the webpage is hosted elsewhere. A bookmarklet can figure out the element to capture, to send back to the server for snapping. I'll update the question.

Comment: I've managed to use this library to take screenshots of other people's websites...  the way I've done it is to inject my own js into the other website using a technique like jquerify uses.